# (Ubuntu 16.10) How to pick/encourage a specific solution proposed by aptitude using only command-line arguments?

Tags: ubuntu, aptitude

According to `aptitude`, the `ubuntu-mate-desktop` and `ubuntu-mate-core` packages recommend the `ntp` package, which conflicts with the `openntpd` package that we use. Interactively, it's easy to ask `aptitude` to leave `openntpd` alone and not install `ntp`. However, because I don't want to have to install MATE interactively after each reinstall of this server, I would like to know if it's possibly to encourage/discourage a given solution non-interactively using only command-line arguments to `aptitude`.

Comment: I'm not overly familiar with this issue, but would the answer to this question help? It would require a little scripting, though. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14392525/passing-arguments-to-an-interactive-program-non-interactively

Comment: I like the idea, @XtraSimplicity, but since the solutions proposed by `aptitude` are numbered I'm afraid that, at a future invocation of the script, the right solution may have a different number.

Comment: @XtraSimplicity, I'm using 16.10 in fact. I wasn't allowed to tag my question as such, because I'm of low reputation. But, of course, regardless of this perhaps being a problem specific to 16.10 and regardless of me perhaps chosing to get rid of openntp, the generic question remains. :)

Comment: ahhh; I've submitted an edit for peer review -- I can't add the tag either, unfortunately (not enough rep on SF), with an updated title.

I'm currently having a play around with this on a vagrant box. If I find a solution that works for me, I'll post it here. :)

Comment: I deleted my comment before, as I realised that I messed something up.. So, I reinstalled the openntpd and ubuntu-mate packages, and can confirm that ntp has *not* been installed. :)

The commands I executed (after installing openntpd using `apt-get install openntpd` (I'm an apt user, rather than aptitude)) along with the output I received are shown [here](http://pastebin.com/KXgmVCjt). A summary of the installed packages can be seen [here](http://pastebin.com/PEhh3qH6).

Comment: For the most part, I followed [this](http://tipsonubuntu.com/2016/09/23/install-mate-desktop-1-16-ubuntu-16-04/) tutorial (i.e. I used the PPAs mentioned in that link), but installed the `ubuntu-mate-desktop` and `ubuntu-mate-core` packages as you would usually.

Answer (score 2):

When you say 'recommends', does this help:

```
--with(out)-recommends Specify whether or not to treat recommends as
                       strong dependencies.
```

Comment: Thanks, @Halfgaar. I didn't know that option. But, the downside to that is that it'll skip *a lot* of recommended packages, so that `aptitude` will end up installing 67 instead of 245 packages. :-/